# how to check whether a view is covered by a Dialog in Android

Tags: android, view, android-dialogfragment

if a dialog is shown like bottom sheet, the view in the bottom of previous activity is totally covered by the dialog, how to check which view is covered or uncovered by code?

the scenario is exampled in the following picture

[image]


[image]

Comment: Dialogs have an isVisible function.

Comment: @TaslimOseni, that's not the question. Question is about the view under the dialog. Not the dialog itself.